# web page doesn't display in iPhone (Xcode 5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

i want to display a web page in my app but it doesn't work

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIWebView *web1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 640.0)];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    web1.delegate = self ;
    [web1 loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.view addSubview:web1];
}
```

Comment: that code is fine and works alright - please show the implementation the delegate methods then

Comment: Have you added `UIWebViewDelegate` in your .h file? Add it and it will work.

Comment: @z22 no it works either way ;) protocol definitions are nice but not required. I keep reading this on SO and in 99% of the cases, it is not needed -- oh and it doesn't have to be in h file either while we are at it :D)

Comment: @Daij-Djan You are so right. I tried it without the protocol definition and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @Suhail- I tried it using `http` and it worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just replace this method

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
```

in to

```
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
```

i tried your code is

```
UIWebView *web1 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[web1 loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:web1];
```

the output is [image]

Comment: @z22,@ Daij-Djan i tried this code, i got the output and then I posted this code , have u tired the questioner code , why u down vote my code, i given the correct answer in the alternate way